# Error #1064 (sintaxis) en base de datos MySQL. Subida a phpMyAdmin (para restaurar instalación WordPress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, sintaxis

qué tal? Estoy intentado restaurar una instalación wordpress y me aparece un problema a la hora de importar la base de datos MySQL del blog. Error código #1064   Como tal, la línea cuatro es una línea de división, --------------------, estoy perdidillo.

El error que aparece es el siguiente:

```
*consulta SQL:


--
-- Current Database: `vj5uq0x_siseo`

USE 'vj5uq0x_siseo'
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ''vj5uq0x_siseo'' en la linea 4*
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en el archivo en cuestión:

```
*-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.47, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: vj5uq0x_siseo
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.47-cll-lve

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;*
```

Comment: ¿Qué código estás ejecutando y qué contexto? El error parece estar aquí `USE 'vj5uq0x_siseo'`, creo que no se debe poner comillas simples ahí. No tiene nada que ver con la línea 4 del resultado del dump, sino con la línea 4 de otro código.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano., gracias por contestar. El archivo es una base de datos MySQL que pretendo subir a hosting para restaurar un blog. El archivo lo voy modificando con Notepad++, lo actualizo y subo de nuevo...y conforme me da errores diferentes. 
Mi objetivo: una nueva instalación "limpia" de WP, restaurante base de datos y archivos, contenidos en el back-up más reciente. Todo desde cPanel y con phpMyAdmin.

Comment: No entiendo en qué entra Notepad aquí ¿? Si hiciste un dump de la BD, puedes usar directamente un comando mysql para hacer la restauración en el otro sitio.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, gracias. Mis conocimientos, de momento son bastante limitados, por lo que ciertos conceptos que comentas no los domino.

Comment: Lo que quise decir es que el error no estaría en el código o archivo con instrucciones SQL que se ha generado al crear la copia de seguridad, sino en otra parte del código donde ejecutabas `USE 'vj5uq0x_siseo'`. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto,  puedes poner como respuesta cuál ha sido la solución, para que sirva o otros que en futuro tuvieran un problema similar.